# Specifying the setters to be used by Hibernate's aliasToBean

Tags: java, hibernate, setter

I'm using `aliasToBean` to transfrom a Criteria resultset to my custom DTO;

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CustomEntity.class));
```

One of the properties; `id` gets returned as an Integer.

I have the following two setters:

```
public void setId(Integer Id) {
  this.uitId = String.valueOf(Id);
}
public void setId(String Id) {
  this.uitId = Id;
}
```

And I get the following exception:

```
10:43:30.009 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor -   IllegalArgumentException in class: com.package.example.CustomEntity, setter method of property: Id
10:43:30.011 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - expected type: java.lang.String, actual value: java.lang.Integer
```

So the transformer is picking the wrong setter.

### *Q:* is there any way to tell the transformer which setter to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your custom DTO should have a setter as defined in JavaBeans
But you can add additional methods to manipulate the fields, but Hibernate needs the proper setters.

But I usually prefer getting the results manually, such as via `query.list()` which returns a `List<Object[]>` and build the DTO by extracting form the list.

Comment: I'm not following you, it has the proper setter, it just has another overloaded setter. If I remove the `setId(String Id)` method is runs with no problems.Dou you mean that the parameter has to be the same type as the member variable?

Comment: The problem is with the overloaded setter, you should not overload the setter(to comply with Java Beans spec). This way you're violating the spec which creates ambiguity for Hibernate(and many other frameworks which assume your DTOs follow the Java Beans spec)